# gnuplot lines with hypertext points?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to get a linespoints plot with the points being hypertext.  So far, I've managed to get linespoints working but without hypertext and I've split it into two plots overlaid, one with lines one with hypertext points. While the second "works", it results in an extra key for the points.  Ideally, I want linespoints key entries for each line and points combination, not a line key and a points key.

Comment: Could you show some code and the figure that you have managed to obtain so far? I do not know what you mean by "hypertext points". Do these contain a web link somehow?

Comment: @Miguel See http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_svg_5.0/hypertext.html

Comment: @Christoph Cool, I didn't know this was possible. Is it new in 5.0?

Comment: @Miguel Yes, and it works only for some terminals (wxt, svg, canvas, qt?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That may be possible with a bit cheating. Usually the `hypertext` is shown only if also `points` is set. Since the area which is active for the hypertext depends on the point size, you can draw all points `with linespoints` and then use a transparent point when plotting the labels:

```
set samples 11
set xrange [0:10]
plot '+' using 1:1:1 with linespoints pt 7 ps var title 'mytitle',\
     '+' using 1:1:(sprintf('(%d,%d)', $1, $1)):1 with labels hypertext point pt 7 lc rgb '#ff000000' notitle
```

Note for other users: The `hypertext` option was introduced in version 5.0.

Comment: That was lovely. Thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to get transparent points to work here using code like this. They just show up black. What am I missing?

Comment: Huh, it looks like transparency on points works in the `svg` renderer, but not the `canvas`. Is this bugworthy? I'm using Firefox 57.0.4 on Debian unstable for both formats, in case this could be an issue with my browser or some library rather than `gnuplot` itself.

Comment: Yes, transparent line colors seem not to be implemented for the canvas terminal, compare also http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas_5.2/rgba_lines.html with http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_svg_5.2/rgba_lines.html. I think that isn't a bug, but simply missing mainenance of the canvas terminal code. Since very few developers are actually working on the gnuplot code, some terminals take quite some time to support all features.