# hyperlink labels on multiple plots with legend and different colors

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file with the first column containing the "names" associated with the row. To handle this when working I use:

```
plot 'myfile' using 2:3:(sprintf("%s (%.2g,%.2g)",strcol(1),$2,$3))
        title 'plot1' with labels hypertext point pt 1 lw 2
```

The problem occurs if I need two plots:

```
plot 'myfile' using 2:3:(sprintf("%s (%.2g,%.2g)",strcol(1),$2,$3)) 
        title 'plot1' with labels hypertext point pt 1 lw 2, 
     'myfile' using 2:4:(sprintf("%s (%.2g,%.2g)",strcol(1),$2,$4)) 
        title 'plot1' with labels hypertext point pt 1 lw 2
```

No automatic coloring is applied to the points, and the legend shows only titles, no matching points. If I color each plot manually (`lc "red"` on the first for example) I can get past the color problem, but the legend still contains no points.

The `gnuplot` scripts are generated by me with a script, so I can automate from there, but I would prefer `gnuplot` handle the coloring automatically, and in any case I would like the legend to have the relevant points, and not just the title (I may be able to modify [gnuplot lines with hypertext points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241798/gnuplot-lines-with-hypertext-points), but I'm looking for a solution with only points, preferably with no additional fake plots).

Some sample input for fun:

```
name x y y1
a    0 1 2
b    1 2 3
c    3 4 5
```

Expected output is two point plots (on same graph of course) with two colors, labels on hover (hyperlinks) showing the value of column "name", and a legend showing the appropriate point symbol+marker (say titles are "y" and "y1").

Comment: Could you include a sample input so we can experiment with it?

Comment: @choroba You got it. I'll just mention that I got this to work by making 4 plots - two "real" ones, and two for hyperlinks, a-la the other SO question. I'm hoping for something neater.

Comment: Hm, I can't find a way how not to use fake plots. You can replace the `title`s by `title columnhead` to extract the titles from the data, but that's all I could improve.

Comment: I'd also use `lc 1` (the 1 generated by a script) instead of `lc "red"`.